# set default value for selectonemenu

Tags: jsf

I have a select menu like this :

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{serverMB.selectedServerType}"  >
    <f:converter binding="#{serverTypeConverter}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{serverMB.serverTypesList}" var="servertypes"
            itemLabel="#{servertypes.server_type_name}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{serverMB.changeSelectedOneMenuServerType}" render="selectservertype"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I want the default value of the select menu to be the value of one object that has been filled before, something like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{serverMB.selectedServerType}" default="serverMB.server.servertype">   // <- default
```

or like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{serverMB.selectedServerType}">
    <f:converter binding="#{serverTypeConverter}"/>
    <f:selectItem value"serverMB.server.servertype"/> <-   but this item was the first one and has been selected  
    <f:selectItems value="#{serverMB.serverTypesList}" var="servertypes"
            itemLabel="#{servertypes.server_type_name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: just set this `#{serverMB.selectedServerType}` to your default value and the selectOne will be set with it as default

Comment: i dont understand your mean , how to set to my default value ?

Comment: On your `serverMB` before you render the page on a @PostConstruct method or even in the construtor you can set the `selectedServerType = objectThatHasTheDefaulValue` then the JSF will do the rest.

Comment: yes thanks , but jsf doesn't have any property like default value for selectonemenu list ?

Comment: It doesnt need because the object (value) is controlled by the bean then when you set the object on the bean it will evaluate as default.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do something like this if your object is already populated when you call the page, if it is not, it will show the `<f:selectItem/>` message:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{serverMB.server.servertype}">
    <f:converter binding="#{serverTypeConverter}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a Server..." />
    <f:selectItems value="#{serverMB.serverTypesList}" var="servertypes"
            itemLabel="#{servertypes.server_type_name}"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{serverMB.changeSelectedOneMenuServerType}" 
            render="selectservertype"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: i did it but it push the select a server lable at the end of the list !

Comment: The Server which will appear is the one who belongs to the object you are sending to the page.Is that what you want?

Comment: From list<obj> how you can do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [OmniFaces converter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter).

Here is my example. It works fine for me. (Note: Year is a object. Make sure, you have equals implemented. Year is `name` and `id` only.)

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.user.year}"
        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select a year." itemValue="#{null}"
            noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allyears}" var="year"
            itemValue="#{year}" itemLabel="#{year.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```