# How to set default value of <p:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a jsf containing two `<p:selectOneMenu ...>` components.

Part of JSF:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="speakerLanguage"
        value="#{speakerAddFormView.currentSpeaker.nativLang1}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Language" itemValue="-1" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{speakerAddFormView.languages.entrySet()}"
            var="languages" itemLabel="#{languages.key}"
            itemValue="#{languages.value}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{speakerAddFormView.updateStateSecondNativeLangSOM}"
            update="speakerLanguage2" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:selectOneMenu id="speakerLanguage2"
        value="#{speakerAddFormView.currentSpeaker.nativLang2}"
        disabled="#{speakerAddFormView.disableSecondNativeLangSOM}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select second Language" itemValue="-1" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{speakerAddFormView.languages.entrySet()}"
            var="languages" itemLabel="#{languages.key}"
            itemValue="#{languages.value}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Within my bean I have a `public static final Map<String, String> LANGUAGE_CODES = new TreeMap<String, String>();`  containing native languages.  This `TreeMap` is referenced at initialization of the bean at:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.languages = ConstantCodes.LANGUAGE_CODES;
}
```

When I reload the page, the both `<p:selectOneMenus >` are seleected not to the default `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select  Language" itemValue="-1" />` or `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select second Language" itemValue="-1" />`.

Screen Snip: 
[image: Wrong selected entries]

**Edit:** These two items are selected from the beginning. 
[image: Selected Items]

Is there a way to force the default selected value ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set default value for selectonemenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048994/set-default-value-for-selectonemenu)

Comment: are you using a session scoped bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `nativLang1` and `nativLang2` to `-1` in your `@PostConstruct` method.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("initializing");
    this.languages = ConstantCodes.LANGUAGE_CODES;
    nativLang1 = "-1";
    nativLang2 = "-1";
}
```